# How to sort a collection of UTF-8 strings containing non-Latin chars in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: sorting, utf-8, laravel-5.3, collation, laravel-collection

Folks, I want to **sort** following nested `collection` **by string**  **alphabeticaly**:

```
$collection = collect([
    ["name"=>"maroon"],
    ["name"=>"zoo"],
    ["name"=>"ábel"],
    ["name"=>"élof"]
])->sortBy("name");
```

**I would expect**:

```
1=> "ábel"
2=> "élof"
3=> "maroon"
4=> "zoo"
```

**I got instead**:

```
1=> "maroon"
2=> "zoo"
3=> "ábel"
4=> "élof"
```

I seen some PHP threads for this, but I am curious if there is any Laravel workaround for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Solid way to do it:

```
$blank = array();
$collection = collect([
    ["name"=>"maroon"],
    ["name"=>"zoo"],
    ["name"=>"ábel"],
    ["name"=>"élof"]
])->toArray();

$count = count($collection);

for ($x=0; $x < $count; $x++) { 
    $blank[$x] = $collection[$x]['name'];
}

$collator = collator_create('en_US');
var_export($blank);
collator_sort( $collator, $blank );
var_export( $blank );

dd($blank);
```

**Outputs:**

```
array (
  0 => 'maroon',
  1 => 'zoo',
  2 => 'ábel',
  3 => 'élof',
)array (
  0 => 'ábel',
  1 => 'élof',
  2 => 'maroon',
  3 => 'zoo',
)
```

**Laravel Pretty Output:**

```
array:4 [
  0 => "ábel"
  1 => "élof"
  2 => "maroon"
  3 => "zoo"
]
```

For personal Reading and reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php

Hope this answer helps, sorry for late response =)

Answer (score 6):

Well, I had this problem and I was able to solve it like this:

```
$list = $Company->administrator->sortBy(function($adm){
   return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $adm->person->name);
});
```

My environment was Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7.1

Comment: In some cases you might want to add an `strtolower` on the property you are sorting by

Answer (score 4):

**You don't need to use the Collator class in this case.** Laravel's collection `sortBy` uses `asort()` and `arsort()` internally, which has the `SORT_LOCALE_STRING` flag for sorting according to the currently set locale.

So, your example can be written as follows:

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'fr_FR.utf8'); // No need to set this if you're doing it elsewhere

$collection = collect([
    ["name"=>"maroon"],
    ["name"=>"zoo"],
    ["name"=>"ábel"],
    ["name"=>"élof"]
])->sortBy("name", SORT_LOCALE_STRING); // Signals to arsort() to take locale into consideration
```

This also means you don't have to convert back-and-forth from a generic PHP array to a Laravel collection.

Comment: `setlocale()` is not threadsafe. See the warning: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php